# How can I decode a base64 string in Adaptive-Cards payload?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I need to decode a base64 string being sent from an external service to an MS-Teams Adaptive-Card via a webhook.

I have the webhook setup, tested with postman, all very easy, but I need to somehow decode a base64 string included in the payload, for example;

{
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"@type": "MessageCard",
"themeColor": "0072C6",
"title": "How to decode a base64 string?",
"text":"eg 'aGVsbG8='"
}

Anyone know if this is possible please?

TIA.

Jarrod.

Comment: Thats not possible inside AdaptiveCards as far as i know...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to decode the code inside the Adaptive card.